# Is storing sensitive information in Vue store safe from 3rd party?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

We have a Vue app that creates and manages user access to an API. We create API keys and display to the user, asking them to save it somewhere before leaving the page, since we only store the hashed version of it ourselves in our backend.

My question is: Since it is an API key *that the user is allowed to have access to*, is it ok to save the API key in the Vue store (until the next refresh), or could it somehow be accessed by a third party from there?

- I know that if this were a JWT token it would be fine, but that has a
  time limit which puts me more at ease.
- I also know that generally a single page app should never store API keys anywhere, but I wonder whether that rule applies here since we don't have to hide it from the user, only 3rd parties

Comment: I'm not sure if the premise of the question makes sense. What's the threat model? If the threat you're trying to fight is that the user's browser might be compromised (e.g. by a malicious extension), then the data can leak no matter how you present it to the user.

Comment: Yes @Etheryte, I suppose that is the threat model. And your right, in that case the key would be exposed no matter where it is. Just looking to see whether there are any other circumstances I'm missing.

Comment: In general, keeping data in Vue is no different than keeping it in a regular Javascript variable, just with more steps. So as long as you don't put it in a-la local storage or a cookie or etc, storing the result in Vue is no more dangerous than other options you have. In the end, you need to send the data to the browser for the user to see it and if the browser is compromised, there isn't anything you can do.

Comment: No data is safe on client side. You need to be aware what kind of unsafe situations you're taking into account in order to estimate safety. Storing sensitive data to local storage isn't drastically more unsafe. If a culprit has access to client side to the point LS or cookies can be accessed, we're already deep in trouble.

Comment: There is one threat model which should be kept in mind with regards to storing things, which is different webapps on separate subdomains. If you own an app at `https://foo.example.com` and there's another team's/company's/etc app at `https://bar.example.com`, localStorage will be separate between the two. However, with cookies it is possible to leak data through this barrier if not configured correctly, in which case you could be in trouble when the other wepapp gets pwned despite your own best efforts.